# Implementing From on a polymorphic type

Tags: rust, type-conversion, traits

I am writing a struct that functions as a thin wrapper over an existing struct.  The existing struct isn't fixed, so I've written it as a type parameter (see struct `B` below).  I would like `B` to preserve convertibility (i.e. `From`/`Into`) based on the internal wrapped type, i.e. if `A1` is convertible to `A` then `B<A1>` should be convertible to `B<A>` as well.

I tried the following code:

```
pub struct A {}
pub struct A1 {}
impl From<A1> for A {
    fn from(a1: A1) -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

pub struct B<T> {
    t: T,
    other_stuff: String,
}
impl<T, U: Into<T>> From<B<U>> for B<T> {
    fn from(b: B<U>) -> Self {
        Self {
            t: b.t.into(),
            other_stuff: b.other_stuff,
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // I would like this to work:
    let ba1: B<A1> = B{ t: A1{}, other_stuff: "abc".to_owned() };
    let ba: B<A> = ba1.into();
}
```

It produces a compilation error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<B<_>>` for type `B<_>`:
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | impl<T, U: Into<T>> From<B<U>> for B<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for T;
```

I think I understand why the error arises (because converting `B<A>` to `B<A>` is already defined), but how may I rewrite my code to avoid the error?

Comment: I've run into this one a few times - as you've seen, Rust's orphan rules prevent this. As there isn't a way to exclude types in trait bounds, you can't do this. In fact this exact issue is blocking stabilisation of the never type currently.

Comment: This will probably be solved by specialization once [RFC1210](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) lands.